# Error when deleting an item from listview in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I wanted to learn how to use `sqlite` in android so I used the following code from a tutorials website but when I ran it , If I delete the first entry in the `listview` the next entry would give

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
>   with a size of 0 in the `DisplayContact` class.

So I wanted to know how to fix it, I don't know if the problem is in the listview or the arraylist.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code which shows the error

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
{
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0)
{
                Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                if (rs != null && rs.getCount() > 0)
{
                    rs.moveToFirst();
                }

String dat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE));
String emai = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL));
String stree = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET));
String plac = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY));
String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
if (!rs.isClosed())
{
rs.close();
}
```

And here is the code to delete an entry

```
    case R.id.Delete_Contact:                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
{
mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
} )
.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
{ }
}
);
                AlertDialog d =builder.create();
                d.setTitle("Are you sure?");
                d.show();
                return true;
            default:
```

This is the logcat output         05-20

```
12:59:33.953 E/AndroidRuntime(25513): Process: com.myelse.sqlcontacts, PID: 25513
    05-20 12:59:33.953 E/AndroidRuntime(25513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myelse.sqlcontacts/com.myelse.sqlcontacts.DisplayContact}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
    05-20 12:59:33.953 E/AndroidRuntime(25513): at com.myelse.sqlcontacts.DisplayContact.onCreate(DisplayContact.java:51)
```

Edit: This is the code for the arraylist and arrayadapter in the mainactivity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList arraylist = mydb.getAllContacts();
    arrayadapter= new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,arraylist);
    arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                int id_to_search=arg2+1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id_to_search + "" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", id_to_search);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayContact.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    );

}
```

Comment: I am assuming you need to re-load the array and then update the ListAdapter because the data changed.

Comment: I tried to call the arraylist which is from another class it gave me nullpointerexception I don't know how to simultaneously delete from the database and the arraylist

Comment: can we see the code for the `ArrayList`

Comment: please post proper code

Comment: @andre3wap I edited the code for arraylist.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar please specify missing code I don't want to clutter the post with all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @parth mehta for the responce , but the only solution that I found to preserve order after deleting an entry was to copy all records to a temporary table without the id column and then moving them back to the original table after each delete.
Using insert into table 1 () select from table2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
```

> **mydb.getData(Value)** will return only one row, where the "id" = Value

So, when you delete this single row, the cursor returns an **IndexOutOfBoundsException**.

One possible solution is to modify your `getData` function as follows:

```
       public Cursor getData(){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts, null );
          return res;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the error has gone but now the id in the listview after delete becomes less by one from the sqldatabase so when I for example press on an item in the list I actually get the previous entry registered in the database.

Comment: And strangely in the database when I delete item with id 1 it starts from id 2 but in the listview it still starts from id 1

Comment: Can I reset the id column in the database Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add Notifydatsetchange() after delete event

Comment: Thanks I tried that but since the adapter is declared in another class it gives null pointer exception but as I answered the only way I found effective is using sql commands